# How can I sort based on a next record field in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that includes a key field, a following key, and up to two previous keys. How can I create a result that is sorted based on the next record being equal to the following key?

```
KEY,PRKEY1,PRKEY2,FLWKEY   
-------------------------------
3701401,0000000,0000000,3701403
3701403,3701401,0000000,3701421
3701402,0000000,0000000,3701404
3701404,3701402,0000000,3701421
3701421,3701404,3701403,3701405
3701405,3701421,0000000,3701423
3701299,0000000,0000000,3701210
3701210,3701299,0000000,3702007
3702007,3701210,0000000,3701005
3701005,3702007,0000000,3701423
3701423,3701405,3701005,3701411
3701413,0000000,0000000,3701411
3701411,3701423,3701413,3701431
3701431,3701411,3701005,3701455
3701451,0000000,0000000,3701455
3701455,3701431,3701451,3701443
3701443,3701455,0000000,3701445
3701445,3701443,0000000,3701432
3701432,3701445,0000000,3701434
3701434,3701432,0000000,3701435
3701435,3701434,0000000,0000000
```

Result should look like:

```
KEY,PRKEY1,PRKEY2,FLWKEY
-------------------------------    
3701401,0000000,0000000,3701403
3701403,3701401,0000000,3701421
3701421,3701404,3701403,3701405
3701405,3701421,0000000,3701423
3701423,3701405,3701005,3701411
3701411,3701423,3701413,3701431
3701431,3701411,3701005,3701455
3701455,3701431,3701451,3701443
3701443,3701455,0000000,3701445
3701445,3701443,0000000,3701432
3701432,3701445,0000000,3701434
3701434,3701432,0000000,3701435
3701435,3701434,0000000,0000000
```

Thanks in advance. I only have about 50k records to sort out this way.

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: And an example of what you want as a result

Comment: looking at your data, it's not clear to me what you're asking.  There are multiple rows that share the same FLWKEY, so there is not a 1:1 relation and therefore there is no clear answer to what you're asking.  If you'd like them sorted by the FLWKEY value you could try something like: SELECT a.* FROM table a JOIN table b ON a.KEY = b.FLWKEY ORDER BY b.FLWKEY;

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "based on the next record being...". What is "the next" record for you?

Comment: it starts out with the first record of a group, that record references the next record in the flwkey field, and so on. The prkey(x), though not really relevant to this question identifies the previous record(s) (there are legs in this scenario). What i want to do is identify the trunk, at this point, and sort it in its order.

Comment: @HannoBinder: he wants a linked list in its own order.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH    q (key, prkey1, prkey2, flwkey, init, lvl) AS
        (
        SELECT  *, key, 1
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   key = 3701401
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  mt.*, q.init, q.lvl + 1
        FROM    q
        JOIN    mytable mt
        ON      mt.key = q.flwkey
        )
SELECT  key, prkey1, prkey2, flwkey
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        init, lvl
```

It's a linked list which you need to traverse in a recursive CTE.

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d4a1/5)